# Enforcing Password Policy on an Instance

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way that I can enforce password policy on an entire instance so that I wouldn't have to do it on every login.

Answer (score 1):

You can script it like this for every login, which is already there.

```
USE [master]
GO

SELECT 'ALTER LOGIN ['+name+'] WITH CHECK_POLICY=ON;'
,* FROM sys.sql_logins
WHERE is_policy_checked = 0
GO
```

Copy from the results what you want, and execute it in another query window.